# Document generator for React / Node.js app with digital signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I would like to create a form where the user answers some questions and before clicking on the submit button they also have to sign it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signature-canvas . After submitting, I want the generated **answers and their signature** to be presented in a PDF document, and sent it to an email address using Nodemailer. Which document generator tool would you recommend for this purpose in React and Node? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake for it.